# Why is my Java Application Silently having a fatal error?

Tags: java

I've never seen this, maybe it is a bug in the jvm?

I added some code to solve sudokus:

```
private boolean solve( int row, int col, Cell[][] cells )
{
    if ( row == NUM_PUZZLE_ROWS )
    {
        row = 0;
        col++;
        if ( col == NUM_PUZZLE_COLUMNS )
            return true;
    }
    if ( cells[row][col].getValue() != 0 )  // skip filled cells
        return solve( row + 1, col, cells );

    for (int val = 1; val <= NUM_PUZZLE_ROWS; val++)
    {
        if ( isPossible( row, col, val, cells ) )
        {
            cells[row][col].setValue( val );
            if ( solve( row + 1, col, cells ) )
                return true;
        }
    }

    cells[row][col].setValue( 0 ); // reset on backtrack
    return false;

}

private boolean isPossible(
        int row, int col, int val, Cell[][] cells )
{

    //check the row
    for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++)  // row
    {
        //no duplicates permitted
        if ( val == cells[r][col].getValue() )
            return false;
    }


    //check the column
    for (int c = 0; c < 9; c++) // col
    {
        //no duplicates permitted
        if ( val == cells[row][c].getValue() )
            return false;
    }

    int rowOffset = (row / 3) * 3;
    int colOffset = (col / 3) * 3;

    //check the 3x3 box
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; ++c)
        {
            if ( val == cells[rowOffset + r][colOffset + c].getValue() )
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true; // no violations, so it's possible
}

private boolean solve( Cell[][] cells )
{
    resetPuzzle();
    return solve( 0, 0, cells );
}

public boolean solve()
{
    return solve( cells );
}
```

I trigger this code with the solve button. The code works great. The puzzle is solved and everything works fine. Until I close the application. This does not happen everytime but: It only ever happens when I have solved a puzzle and of those times only happens half the time.

The application closes fine but it returns 1 rather than 0 success and leaves this log file:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d93591e, pid=2368, tid=2040
>
> JRE version: 6.0_27-b07
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.2-b06 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
>    Problematic frame:
>    V  [jvm.dll+0x9591e]
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
>
> ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------
>
> Current thread (0x02be1800):  JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon
>   [_thread_in_vm, id=2040, stack(0x02fa0000,0x02ff0000)]
>
> siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x00000000
>
> Registers: EAX=0x02be20c8, EBX=0x00000000, ECX=0x00000000,
>   EDX=0x02fef89c ESP=0x02fef88c, EBP=0x02fef920, ESI=0x02be1800,
>   EDI=0x02bde6d0 EIP=0x6d93591e, EFLAGS=0x00010202
>
> Top of Stack: (sp=0x02fef88c) 0x02fef88c:   02b002b8 02be1928 02be1800
>   000c3550 0x02fef89c:   02be20c8 000c3528 00000000 02fef97c 0x02fef8ac:
>   7c91084c 000b01a0 7c910981 000b0608 0x02fef8bc:   7c91015d 000c3550
>   000c3530 02fef89c 0x02fef8cc:   02fef8bd 00000001 00000008 00000000
>   0x02fef8dc:   7e428d8b 6d14cea1 02fef8f4 00000000 0x02fef8ec:
>   02fef91c 6d8a2af6 02be1800 02be2df8 0x02fef8fc:   02be1800 02be1928
>   02fef8f8 02be1c88
>
> Instructions: (pc=0x6d93591e) 0x6d9358fe:   78 ff ff ff 89 41 14 8b 45
>   ac c6 04 10 01 8b 4d 0x6d93590e:   b0 8b 55 a8 8b 45 f4 89 04 8a ff 45
>   b0 8b 5d fc 0x6d93591e:   8b 03 8b 48 08 0f b7 51 2a 8b 40 0c 8b 4c 90
>   28 0x6d93592e:   51 56 8d 4d bc e8 d8 a5 07 00 8b 55 18 33 c0 89
>
> Register to memory mapping:
>
> EAX=0x02be20c8 is an unknown value EBX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
>   ECX=0x00000000 is an unknown value EDX=0x02fef89c is pointing into the
>   stack for thread: 0x02be1800 ESP=0x02fef88c is pointing into the stack
>   for thread: 0x02be1800 EBP=0x02fef920 is pointing into the stack for
>   thread: 0x02be1800 ESI=0x02be1800 is a thread EDI=0x02bde6d0 is an
>   unknown value
>
> Stack: [0x02fa0000,0x02ff0000],  sp=0x02fef88c,  free space=318k
>   Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code,
>   C=native code) V  [jvm.dll+0x9591e] V  [jvm.dll+0x9884c] C 
>   [awt.dll+0x6cbbc]  Java_sun_awt_windows_WChoicePeer_create+0x10c C 
>   [USER32.dll+0x8734]  GetDC+0x6d C  [USER32.dll+0x8816]  GetDC+0x14f C 
>   [USER32.dll+0x18ea0]  DefWindowProcW+0x180 C  [USER32.dll+0x18eec] 
>   DefWindowProcW+0x1cc C  [ntdll.dll+0xe473] 
>   KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x13
>
> Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code) j 
>   sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.eventLoop()V+0 j 
>   sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.run()V+52 j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11 v 
>   ~StubRoutines::call_stub
>
> ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------
>
> Java Threads: ( => current thread )   0x02ba1400 JavaThread "Thread-1"
>   daemon [_thread_in_native, id=924, stack(0x03230000,0x03280000)]
>   0x002b6c00 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=3688,
>   stack(0x008c0000,0x00910000)]   0x03136c00 JavaThread
>   "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=376,
>   stack(0x03280000,0x032d0000)]
>   =>0x02be1800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=2040, stack(0x02fa0000,0x02ff0000)]   0x02be0800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown"
>   [_thread_blocked, id=1924, stack(0x02f50000,0x02fa0000)]   0x02bdec00
>   JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3992,
>   stack(0x02f00000,0x02f50000)]   0x02b57c00 JavaThread "Low Memory
>   Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3804,
>   stack(0x02dd0000,0x02e20000)]   0x02b52000 JavaThread "C1
>   CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=612,
>   stack(0x02d80000,0x02dd0000)]   0x02b50400 JavaThread "Attach
>   Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3916,
>   stack(0x02d30000,0x02d80000)]   0x02b4f000 JavaThread "Signal
>   Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3844,
>   stack(0x02ce0000,0x02d30000)]   0x02b48400 JavaThread "Finalizer"
>   daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4092, stack(0x02c90000,0x02ce0000)]
>   0x02b46c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked,
>   id=2828, stack(0x02c40000,0x02c90000)]
>
> Other Threads:   0x02b0ac00 VMThread [stack: 0x02bf0000,0x02c40000]
>   [id=3612]   0x02b63000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x02e20000,0x02e70000]
>   [id=1944]
>
> VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)
>
> VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None
>
> Heap  def new generation   total 4928K, used 823K [0x22990000,
>   0x22ee0000, 0x27ee0000)   eden space 4416K,   7% used [0x22990000,
>   0x229ddc50, 0x22de0000)   from space 512K, 100% used [0x22e60000,
>   0x22ee0000, 0x22ee0000)   to   space 512K,   0% used [0x22de0000,
>   0x22de0000, 0x22e60000)  tenured generation   total 10944K, used 1261K
>   [0x27ee0000, 0x28990000, 0x32990000)    the space 10944K,  11% used
>   [0x27ee0000, 0x2801b590, 0x2801b600, 0x28990000)  compacting perm gen 
>   total 12288K, used 244K [0x32990000, 0x33590000, 0x36990000)    the
>   space 12288K,   1% used [0x32990000, 0x329cd110, 0x329cd200,
>   0x33590000)
>       ro space 10240K,  54% used [0x36990000, 0x36f0f548, 0x36f0f600, 0x37390000)
>       rw space 12288K,  55% used [0x37390000, 0x37a35140, 0x37a35200, 0x37f90000)
>
> Code Cache  [0x00910000, 0x009e0000, 0x02910000)  total_blobs=410
>   nmethods=214 adapters=132 free_code_cache=32713344
>   largest_free_block=0
>
> Dynamic libraries: 0x00400000 - 0x00424000    C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin\java.exe 0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b2000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll 0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll 0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll 0x77e70000 - 0x77f03000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll 0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll 0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll 0x6d8a0000 - 0x6db4f000
>     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll 0x7e410000 -
>   0x7e4a1000    C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll 0x77f10000 - 0x77f59000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll 0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll 0x76390000 - 0x763ad000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL 0x6d850000 - 0x6d85c000   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\verify.dll 0x6d3d0000 - 0x6d3ef000
>     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\java.dll 0x6d890000 -
>   0x6d89f000    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\zip.dll
>   0x6d0b0000 - 0x6d1fc000   C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\awt.dll 0x73000000 - 0x73026000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV 0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll 0x774e0000 - 0x7761e000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll 0x773d0000 - 0x774d3000
>     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.6028_x-ww_61e65202\COMCTL32.dll
>   0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll 0x5ad70000 -
>   0x5ada8000    C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll 0x6d2e0000 - 0x6d32f000
>     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\fontmanager.dll 0x74720000
>   - 0x7476c000  C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll 0x755c0000 - 0x755ee000   C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime 0x7c9c0000 - 0x7d1d7000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll 0x6d6b0000 - 0x6d6c3000     C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\net.dll 0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll 0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll 0x6d6d0000 - 0x6d6d9000     C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\bin\nio.dll 0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000
>     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
>
> VM Arguments: jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>   -Djava.security.policy=applet.policy  java_command: SudokuApp Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD
>
> Environment Variables: CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
>   PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio
>   Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Roxio
>   Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program
>   Files\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\
>   USERNAME=0935231 OS=Windows_NT PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model
>   42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
>
> ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------
>
> OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3
>
> CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 42
>   stepping 7, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1,
>   sse4.2, popcnt, ht
>
> Memory: 4k page, physical 3318716k(2487016k free), swap
>   7866808k(7197684k free)
>
> vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.2-b06) for windows-x86 JRE
>   (1.6.0_27-b07), built on Jul 19 2011 01:04:42 by "java_re" with MS
>   VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)
>
> time: Mon Nov 28 12:30:52 2011 elapsed time: 10 seconds

What could be wrong?
The code does not throw any exceptions and there are no signs of anything going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip seems souspicious? What QTJava.zip do and it is absolutetly necessary you save it in the lib/ext folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've found a bug in Java unless you have some native code you're not telling us about.

Comment: You should submit that as a bug then. Make sure to include the full program and also any input to it.